# ASP.NET MVC exception logging

Tags: asp.net, logging

i have just taken over an app that has a lot of code like below where exceptions are just caught and Console.Write(xxx) is there.

I would like to change this so i have a simple log to review everything there is a Console.write() now.

What is the simplest way for getting this setup in asp.net mvc to have a file to view on the IIS server.

```
try
{
    SmtpClient c = new SmtpClient("mail.xxx.org");
    c.Send(msg);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Also, [this blog](http://blog.dantup.me.uk/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-handleerror-attribute-custom.html) has a good explanation of how to log errors caught by the [HandleError] attribute.

Comment: There are other similar questions re: ASP.NET MVC.  Please see... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032373/asp-net-mvc-exception-logging-combined-with-error-handling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try the ELMAH library.

Check [the project site](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC) for some examples.

Scott Hanselman has also written [a blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx) or two about it.

Comment: got setup with this in < 2 mins